# Aptana studio 3 workspace shared between windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, share, aptana

I mostly use Linux for my programming. But ocassionally I use windows when I am somewhere I only have access to that. Is it possible to save my workspace, created in linux, to a USB drive and then import it under windows without it breaking when I import it back into linux?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use PortableApps http://portableapps.com/node/5883

Or your VCS of choice, which is what I do. This way would be easier for dealing with platform dependent code, but would likely require more work.